# Error when adding new assets in dagster which is dependent on duckdb

Tags: python, ubuntu, dbt, duckdb, dagster

When I try to add a new asset in dagster which should create a table based on the csv file gotten from a previous asset, I get the error on my dagster server which runs on localhost:3000

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterInvalidDefinitionError: resource with key 'duckdb' required by op 'create_scores_table' was not provided. Please provide a ResourceDefinition to key 'duckdb', or change the required key to one of the following keys which points to an ResourceDefinition: ['io_manager']

  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/server.py", line 295, in __init__
    self._loaded_repositories: Optional[LoadedRepositories] = LoadedRepositories(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/server.py", line 139, in __init__
    loadable_targets = get_loadable_targets(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/utils.py", line 47, in get_loadable_targets
    else loadable_targets_from_python_module(module_name, working_directory)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/workspace/autodiscovery.py", line 35, in loadable_targets_from_python_module
    module = load_python_module(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/code_pointer.py", line 135, in load_python_module
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dagster_sportsdata/dagster_sportsdata/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    defs = Definitions(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/definitions_class.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._created_pending_or_normal_repo = _create_repository_using_definitions_args(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/definitions_class.py", line 304, in _create_repository_using_definitions_args
    def created_repo():
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/decorators/repository_decorator.py", line 118, in __call__
    repository_definitions = fn()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/definitions_class.py", line 306, in created_repo
    *with_resources(assets or [], resource_defs),
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/with_resources.py", line 105, in with_resources
    transformed_defs.append(cast(T, definition.with_resources(resource_defs)))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/assets.py", line 1308, in with_resources
    attributes_dict["resource_defs"] = merge_resource_defs(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/resource_requirement.py", line 268, in merge_resource_defs
    ensure_requirements_satisfied(
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/dbt_dagster_proj/dbt_dags/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/definitions/resource_requirement.py", line 228, in ensure_requirements_satisfied
    raise DagsterInvalidDefinitionError(
```

This is my directory tree structure:

```
.
├── dagster_sportsdata
│   ├── assets.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── assets.cpython-39.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
├── dagster_sportsdata.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── dagster_sportsdata_tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_assets.py
├── footballstanding.csv
├── footscores.csv
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tmp6jvpinn6
    ├── history
    │   ├── runs
    │   │   ├── 22c4874e-639f-4014-bd0c-3b365a1f1b09.db
    │   │   └── index.db
    │   └── runs.db
    ├── schedules
    │   └── schedules.db
    └── storage
        ├── 22c4874e-639f-4014-bd0c-3b365a1f1b09
        │   └── compute_logs
        │       ├── mosjsvar.complete
        │       ├── mosjsvar.err
        │       └── mosjsvar.out
        └── league_standing
```

And this is my asset.py file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from dagster import AssetExecutionContext, asset
from dagster_duckdb import DuckDBResource
from dagster import Definitions
import os


current_directory = os.getcwd() 
database_file = os.path.join(current_directory, "my_duckdb_database.duckdb")


@asset
def league_standing():
    urls = [
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/ligue-1-table", "source": "Ligue 1"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table", "source": "Premier League"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/la-liga-table", "source": "la liga"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/bundesliga-table", "source": "Bundesliga"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/serie-a-table", "source": "Seria A"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/eredivisie-table", "source": "Eredivisie"},
    {"url": "https://www.skysports.com/scottish-premier-table", "source": "Scottish premiership"}
    ]
    dfs = []

    for url_info in urls:
        url = url_info["url"]
        source = url_info["source"]

        # Send HTTP Request and Parse HTML
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

        # Find and Extract Table Headers
        table = soup.find("table", class_="standing-table__table")
        headers = table.find_all("th")
        titles = [i.text for i in headers]

        # Create an Empty DataFrame
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=titles)

        # Iterate Through Table Rows and Extract Data
        rows = table.find_all("tr")
        for i in rows[1:]:
            data = i.find_all("td")
            row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in data]  # Apply .strip() to remove \n
            l = len(df)
            df.loc[l] = row

        # Add a column for source URL
        df["Source"] = source

        # Append the DataFrame to the list
        dfs.append(df)

    # Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
    football_standing = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    football_standing.to_csv("footballstanding.csv")


@asset
def get_scores():
    url = "https://www.skysports.com/football-results"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    home_team = soup.find_all("span", class_="matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side1")
    x = [name.strip() for i in home_team for name in i.stripped_strings]

    scores = soup.find_all("span", class_="matches__teamscores")
    s = [name.strip().replace('\n\n', '\n') for i in scores for name in i.stripped_strings]
    appended_scores = [f"{s[i]}\n{s[i+1]}".replace('\n', ' ') for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]

    away_team = soup.find_all("span", class_="matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side2")
    y = [name.strip() for i in away_team for name in i.stripped_strings]

    # Make sure all arrays have the same length
    min_length = min(len(x), len(appended_scores), len(y))
    data = {"Home Team": x[:min_length], "Scores": appended_scores[:min_length], "Away Team": y[:min_length]}
    footballscores = pd.DataFrame(data)
    footballscores.to_csv("footscores.csv")

@asset
def create_scores_table(duckdb: DuckDBResource) -> None:
    sports_df = pd.read_csv(
        "footscores.csv",
        names=['Unnamed: 0', 
               'Home Team', 
               'Scores', 
               'Away Team'],
            
    )

    with duckdb.get_connection() as conn:
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE sports.scores AS SELECT * FROM scores_df")


defs = Definitions(
    assets=[league_standing, get_scores, create_scores_table],
    resources={
        "duckdb": DuckDBResource(
            database=database_file)
            }
)
```

** I noticed that everything seems to work fine until I added this part into the code:**

```
@asset
def create_scores_table(duckdb: DuckDBResource) -> None:
    sports_df = pd.read_csv(
        "footscores.csv",
        names=['Unnamed: 0', 
               'Home Team', 
               'Scores', 
               'Away Team'],
            
    )

    with duckdb.get_connection() as conn:
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE sports.scores AS SELECT * FROM scores_df")


defs = Definitions(
    assets=[league_standing, get_scores, create_scores_table],
    resources={
        "duckdb": DuckDBResource(
            database=database_file)
            }
)
```

**Please Help**